# Can't successfully start Kivy applications on Raspberry Pi 3 with 3.5 in Touchscreen

Tags: python, kivy, egl, raspberry-pi3

I followed every guide I could find on installing Kivy to Raspberry Pi.

My touchscreen works totally fine, I don't think Kivy not launching properly has anything to do with the that.

Trying to launch various Kivy demos will result in what seems to be a partial launch, but then it will just hang.... maybe my config.ini is not correctly configured?

For example, running 'python main.py' for examples/demo/pictures/ gives me:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-25_12.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range position X is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range position Y is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <ADS7846 Touchscreen>
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <ADS7846 Touchscreen> range ABS X position is 0 -     4095
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <ADS7846 Touchscreen> range ABS Y position is 0 - 4095
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <ADS7846 Touchscreen> range ABS pressure is 0 - 65535
```

And then it just hangs forever. No window pops up, nothing.

Same thing happens running from the touchscreen, running through SSH, and running through tightvncserver remote desktop.

**Update:**
No good news, but some more details. Running `python main.py -c kivy:log_level:trace` with a bare-bones application (https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#quickstart) with a keyboard interrupt:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-26_17.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] load file /home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/style.kv
[TRACE  ] [Parser      ] parsing 1271 lines
[TRACE  ] [Parser      ] got directive <kivy 1.0>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Label>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <-Button,-ToggleButton>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <BubbleContent>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <BubbleButton>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Slider>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ProgressBar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SplitterStrip>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Scatter>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <RelativeLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Image,AsyncImage>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <EffectWidget>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TabbedPanelContent>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TabbedPanelStrip>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <StripLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TabbedPanelHeader>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Selector>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TextInput>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TextInputCutCopyPaste>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <CodeInput>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TreeViewNode>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <TreeViewLabel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <StencilView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserListLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserListView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build template for [FileListEntry@FloatLayout+TreeViewNode]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserIconLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserIconView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build template for [FileIconEntry@Widget]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <FileChooserProgress>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Switch>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ModalView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Popup>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SpinnerOption>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Spinner>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionBar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionSeparator>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionButton,ActionToggleButton>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionLabel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionGroup>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionCheck>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionPreviousImage@Image>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionPreviousButton@Button>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionPrevious>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionGroup>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionOverflow>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ActionDropDown>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build template for [AccordionItemTitle@Label]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <AccordionItem>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingSpacer>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingItem>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingBoolean>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingString>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingPath>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingOptions>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingTitle>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingSidebarLabel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <SettingsPanel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <Settings>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <InterfaceWithSidebar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <InterfaceWithSpinner>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <MenuSpinner>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <MenuSidebar>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ContentPanel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <InterfaceWithTabbedPanel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ScrollView>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <VideoPlayerPreview>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <VideoPlayerAnnotation>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <VideoPlayer>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <CheckBox>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ScreenManager>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker_Input@TextInput>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker_Label@Label>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker_Selector@BoxLayout>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorWheel>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] build rule for <ColorPicker>
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[TRACE  ] [Image       ] Unable to use <gif> as loader!
[TRACE  ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 129, in core_register_libs
    level=0)
  File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/core/image/img_ffpyplayer.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ffpyplayer
ImportError: No module named ffpyplayer
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./my.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv <./my.kv> not found
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Actual display size: 720x480
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [ImagePygame ] Load </home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[TRACE  ] [Image       ] '/home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/glsl/default.png', populate to textures (1)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] Found 1 rules for <kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x74333458>
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/roboto> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/gentium-basic> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/local/share/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/fonts> in path list
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] call_fn <kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle object at 0x74317650>, key=size, value=<code object <module> at 0x76553890, file "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/style.kv", line 9>, 'self.texture_size'
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] call_fn => value=[79, 18]
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] call_fn <kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle object at 0x74317650>, key=texture, value=<code object <module> at 0x76553608, file "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/style.kv", line 8>, 'self.texture'
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] call_fn => value=<Texture hash=1945546224 id=0 size=(79, 18) colorfmt='rgba' bufferfmt='ubyte' source=None observers=1>
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] call_fn <kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle object at 0x74317650>, key=pos, value=<code object <module> at 0x765538d8, file "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10>, 'int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)'
[TRACE  ] [Builder     ] call_fn => value=(320, 231)
^C[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 89, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 84, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/base.py", line 327, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/clock.py", line 499, in tick
     usleep(1000000 * (sleeptime - sleep_undershoot))
   File "/home/pi/kivy/kivy/clock.py", line 292, in usleep
     _libc_usleep(int(microseconds))
 KeyboardInterrupt
```

My best guess is it's either the missing ffpyplayer module or something to do with EGL.

Update 2:
Well, I reran the basic application in my Windows Kivy to compare the log (the application successfully launches in my Windows Kivy). ffplayer error still exists, leading me to believe it's some sort of EGL issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [tutorial](http://mattrichardson.com/kivy-gpio-raspberry-pi-touch/index.html) helps you. It uses the same controller as you (ADS7846). Just skip over the GPIO part. There is a part where the [input] section in the file `~/.kivy/config.ini` gets changed:

```
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Comment: I have that exactly. Although that particular section of configuration seems to have to do with the input interface. I can't even launch an app successfully.

Answer (score 0):

i am currently facing the same problem with an Eleduino 10.1 inch capacitive touchscreen. I managed to solve the problem configuring the file: ~/.kivy/config.ini 
Go to [input] section and comment everything. Then, add the following lines:

```
    test = mtdev,/dev/input/event3
    ntrig = mtdev,/dev/input/event1
```